# Parsing Apache Log using Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to get the following:-

**Input**

```
GET /1.1/friendships/list.json?user_id=123 HTTP/1.1
GET /1.1/friendships/list.json HTTP/1.1
GET /1.1/users/show.json?include_entities=1&user_id=321 HTTP/1.1
GET /1.1/friendships/list.json?user_id=234 HTTP/1.1
GET /1.1/friendships/create.json HTTP/1.1
```

**Output**

```
/1.1/friendships/list.json
/1.1/friendships/list.json
/1.1/users/show.json
/1.1/friendships/list.json
/1.1/friendships/create.json
```

I have been able to match till the question mark character. I want to match a character that is either a question mark or a blank space. Here is what I have so far.

```
([A-Z])+ (\S)+[\?]
```

Comment: `r = re.compile(r'\w+ ([/\w\.]+)')` and `r.match(<string>).groups(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression accepts `GET` and `POST`:

```
^(?:GET|POST)\s+([^?\n\r]+).*$
```

Broken down, this says

```
^               # start of line
(?:GET|POST)\s+ # GET or POST literally, at least one whitespace
([^?\s]+)       # not a question mark nor whitespace characters
.*              # 0+ chars afterwards
$               # end of line
```

This needs to be replaced by `\1`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/HZxO7T/2/) and mind the `MULTILINE` flag.

---

In `Python`, this would be:

```
import re

string = """
GET /1.1/friendships/list.json?user_id=123 HTTP/1.1
GET /1.1/friendships/list.json HTTP/1.1
GET /1.1/users/show.json?include_entities=1&user_id=321 HTTP/1.1
GET /1.1/friendships/list.json?user_id=234 HTTP/1.1
GET /1.1/friendships/create.json HTTP/1.1
POST /some/other/url/here
"""

rx = re.compile(r'^(?:GET|POST)\s+([^?\s]+).*$', re.M)
matches = rx.findall(string)
print(matches)
# ['/1.1/friendships/list.json', '/1.1/friendships/list.json', '/1.1/users/show.json', '/1.1/friendships/list.json', '/1.1/friendships/create.json', '/some/other/url/here']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

`GET\s*(\S*?[\?\s])`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kNI5xl/1)

The idea is to search for `?` or  (space) in a non-greedy (aka lazy) approach (denoted by `*?`).
*Group 1* then has the required captured text.